# Android extends Activity

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, extends

I'm developing an Android app. And my classes relationships are like this: 

 **https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CCpA.jpg**

I'm getting some problems about it. The biggest are: 
1) Working with **Context**. SocialNetWorkClass has a SQLiteDatabase object. But I don't know how to work about it. Because I can't pass the Context with constructor from FacebookClass.

2) On FacebookClass I can't use methods like findViewById, because I don't access BaseClass objects (super super class), it's like if I can't use Activity methods.

Aditional informations:

- BaseClass extends android.app.Activity;
- BaseClass and SocialNetworkClass are abstract classes;
- My intention with this hierarchy is produce less code (and reuse code).

Could anyone help me, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why cant you pass the context?

Comment: @zgc7009, because I want to pass the context from FacebookClass to SocialNetworkClass. I tried from constructor method, but I got the error "Cannot refer to 'this' nor 'super' while explicitly invoking a constructor". And the only way I see to pass the context is from constructor. 
The reason: when I call the constructor method from parent I have to SELECT some data from the table to fill an object inside the parent (SocialNetworkClass) class.

Comment: The log @zgc7009 is here: http://pastebin.com/xCepbaNk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to pass a `Context` to any of your classes since they all extend `Activity` which extends `Context`. All your classes have access to the methods in `Context`.
   Side note: consider using Android's `ContentProvider` to manage your SQLiteDatabase. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html
2. Same as 1. Since `FacebookClass` extends `Activity` you can directly call `findViewById()` from `FacebookClass`.

Comment: Did you call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()`?

Comment: Yes, I did! And what I'm finding exists, I use this: LinearLayout lnItens = (LinearLayout) super.findViewById(R.id.ll_add_dioxido);